# CL-WHO HTML generator to file

Tags: html, lisp, generator, cl-who

I'm trying to generate an html file to a file. I'm using with-html-output-to-string, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the functionality to work. I'm not sure if I should use a file stream, with-open-file, and how to get the syntax to work. I've been messing with this for a day, but the code just doesnt run.

Answer (score 1):

```
CL-USER> (who:with-html-output-to-string (out nil :prologue t :indent t)
         (:html
          (:head
           (:title "home"))
          (:body
           (:p "Hello cl."))))
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">

<html>
  <head>
    <title>home
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello cl.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>"
```